# メタからの戻り方をヘルプに書いて欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, ヘルプ

SOに最初に来た頃、メタに迷い込んで戻れなくなったことがありました。
その後、メタに入った後はブラウザのブックマークで戻っていました。
左上隅の StackExchange のアイコンから戻るようになったのは、もっと先のことです。

メタからの戻り方をメタのヘルプに書いていただけないでしょうか?

Comment: どう書けばわかりやすいですか？質問にほしい文章を入れたら追加します。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @jmac 画像を貼り付けることはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist もちろん！写真、文書、両方等、方法は任せます！

Comment: masm、@unarist ご確認ください：http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta

Comment: 良いと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @jmac あ、help/whats-meta じゃなくて権限の方に書いたんですね。了解です。

Comment: @unarist help/whats-metaにも追加できます。しましょうか？

Comment: @jmac まあ権限の方は「メインから見たメタ」、helpの方は「メタの自己紹介」ってことで、このままでいいかと。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[「メタへの参加」権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)の説明を参考にしました。

> #### メタはどこにありますか?
>
> 各ページのフッターに、メタへのリンクがあります。リンクは Stack Exchange サイト スイッチャー (ヘッダーの左上) および「ヘルプ」メニュー (ヘッダーの右上) にもあります。

フッターにリンク？と思ったら、右端の「フィードバック」がそれだったんですね・・・。

追記：書いてはみましたが、メタのヘルプにたどり着けるならヘルプメニューのリンクに気づきそうな気もします。

---

#### メインサイトに戻るには？

ヘッダー左端にある Stack Exchange サイトスイッチャーで、メインサイトとメタサイトを自由に行き来することができます。現在見ているサイト（下の画像ではメタサイト）は太字で表示されます。

[image: Stack Exchange サイトスイッチャー]

また、「ヘルプ」メニューにもリンクが用意されています

[image: ヘルプメニュー]

Comment: 私が書くべきところ、わざわざ書いていただいてすみません。
今後メタのヘルプへのリンクが増えるかもと考えると、重要な項目になると思います。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @masm 当サイトは皆様のものですので、別に問題を定義した人が解決しないといけないわけではありません。問題提議するのも非常にいいですので、解決案がなくても、自由に問題を投稿してください。同じように他人の問題に対していい解決案があれば、ご自由に投稿してください！